# Getting build error on intellij for gradle project

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea

I am trying to build and run a spring boot gradle project on intellij and getting this error:

```
org/gradle/internal/impldep/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableSetorg/gradle/internal/impldep/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableSet
```

and when i try t run gradle command on terminal then getting this:

```
org.gradle.api.internal.classpath.UnknownModuleException: Cannot locate JAR for module 'kotlin-compiler-embeddable-1.3.31-patched-for-gradle' in distribution directory 'C:\gradle-5
.5.1'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.classpath.DefaultModuleRegistry.loadModule(DefaultModuleRegistry.java:147)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.classpath.DefaultModuleRegistry.getModule(DefaultModuleRegistry.java:120)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.classpath.DefaultModuleRegistry.getModules(DefaultModuleRegistry.java:199)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.classpath.DefaultModuleRegistry.access$200(DefaultModuleRegistry.java:48)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.classpath.DefaultModuleRegistry$DefaultModule.getRequiredModules(DefaultModuleRegistry.java:379)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.classpath.DefaultModuleRegistry$DefaultModule.collectRequiredModules(DefaultModuleRegistry.java:413)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.classpath.DefaultModuleRegistry$DefaultModule.collectDependenciesOf(DefaultModuleRegistry.java:425)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.classpath.DefaultModuleRegistry$DefaultModule.collectRequiredModules(DefaultModuleRegistry.java:419)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.classpath.DefaultModuleRegistry$DefaultModule.collectDependenciesOf(DefaultModuleRegistry.java:425)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.classpath.DefaultModuleRegistry$DefaultModule.collectRequiredModules(DefaultModuleRegistry.java:414)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.classpath.DefaultModuleRegistry$DefaultModule.getAllRequiredModules(DefaultModuleRegistry.java:396)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.classpath.DefaultModuleRegistry$DefaultModule.getAllRequiredModulesClasspath(DefaultModuleRegistry.java:403)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultClassPathProvider.findClassPath(DefaultClassPathProvider.java:30)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultClassPathRegistry.getClassPath(DefaultClassPathRegistry.java:34)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:49)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:37)
        at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
```

I tried build and rebuild project but nothing helps...

Comment: Maybe your local Gradle distribution is corrupt as that file should be in the `lib` directory.

Comment: Not sure, It was working fine earlier